# Problem to get dynamically injected content in HTMLUnit

Tags: javascript, html, htmlunit

HTMLUnit version: 2.36.0

I am trying to get this page content (middle part with actual bets):

https://play.livebet.com/#/sport/?type=0&sport=1&game=15095924&competition=543&region=1170001

It seems like it doesn't get injected by JS and I can't get it

I've already tried to wait for it in a loop but it doesn't help

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BEST_SUPPORTED);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("https://play.livebet.com/#/sport/?type=0&sport=1&game=15095924&competition=543&region=1170001");
```

I would love to get this:

```
List<HtmlElement> divTables = page.getByXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'multicolumn-table')]");
```

But it will be only there if the content is loaded of course.

Could anyone please help me find a way to get the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with HtmlUnit (at least version 2.36.0). HtmlUnit's simulation seem to do something different than real browsers regarding RocketLoader (used by this site).

RocketLoader dumps this warning to the log - and as result the javascript required to be executed to get the page content is not executed.

```
WARN  com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole - [ROCKET LOADER]  Placeholder for script 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular.min.js?v=1.7.7" type="text/javascript"></script>
 was detached from document. Script will not be executed.
```

At the moment i have no time to analyze in more detail, will be great if you can spend some time to find the reason (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will take a look at the link you provided. Do you think it is possible that it will work with previous versions of HtmlUnit? I can try going one by one but not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: I've just tried a few versions back and none of them seem to work with RocketLoader :|